# How show clipboard with Applescript

Tags: applescript

I use with applescript the menu of Finder to show Clipboard. 
I would like to know something else or way to show Clipboard. Thank you for your answers.

```
tell application "System Events" to tell process "Finder"
    set frontmost to true
    click menu item "show Clipboard" of menu "Edit" of menu bar 1
end tell
```

Comment: This would involve showing a window. How were you thinking of doing that? To put it another way: how else _would_ you do this?

Answer (score 0):

If the clipboard is text, you can show its contents in an AppleScript dialog box with:

```
try
    display dialog (get the clipboard)
on error
    display dialog "The clipboard is not text."
end try
```

Comment: Hello and thank you for your answer. With menu item it works very well no error. For what I look it is another way to show clipboard . About are the contents of the clipboard embellish with images or text. Let be in Objective-C or Applescript, or python

Comment: Hello and thank you for your answer. With menu item it works very well no error. For what I look it is another way to show clipboard . About are the contents of the clipboard embellish with images or text. Let be in Objective-C or Applescript, or python